# How to replace IE for managing SSRS 2012 reports

Tags: reporting-services

It is no longer possible to install IE from MSFT; the link gives you Edge.  Some of our Win10Pro VMs have no IE installed, and can't get the SSRS 2012 Folder or Report "Manage" dropdown fully populated (i.e. download RDF) using Edge or Chrome.  The Chrome IE addin evidently tries (fails) to load bits from an assumed installed instance of IE.  My workaround is to use other VMs/laptops on the correct domain that still have IE installed.  But isn't Edge supposed to support SSRS?
All our other MSSQL is 2019.  In my role, I am not in a position to upgrade SSRS, I just have to keep it alive while Nero fiddles.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the report you want to manage
2. Click copy address (could vary depending on the browser you use)
3. Paste the address into a new tab or same tab or text editor (whatever you prefer)
4. Add the following to the end of the url "&SelectedTabId=PropertiesTab&ViewMode=List" (no quotes)
5. Hit enter to go to the url

Example:
http://127.0.0.1/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTestFolder%2fTestReport&SelectedTabId=PropertiesTab&ViewMode=List